# Correct use of "immediately"

Tags: adverbs, adverb-position

I have two variants of one sentence and I want to find out which of them is correct and why:

1. So you'll see immediately the notification when the crucial for you information changes.
2. So you’ll immediately see the notification when information crucial for you changes.

Main concern is position of "immediately".

Comment: Either position is *allowed*, though in many dialects putting the adverb "immediately" directly before the verb is preferred.

Comment: Or *So you’ll see the notification **immediately** when information crucial **to** you changes* (I at least don't like *crucial **for** you* there). All three positions for *immediately* are perfectly okay, but ***the crucial for/to you information*** in #1 is a total no-no.

Comment: @FF Yes, I rushed to check 'crucial for you'; I can't say it's not allowable. I prefer your rewrite; you can get away with 'So you'll see immediately the notification when the crucial (for you) information changes.' Brackets can cover a multitude of syntax sins.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Immidiately* is an adverb [of time], and just as the tag summary mentions, the position of an adverb often depends on the kind of adverb (manner, place, time, degree) and if the word being modified is a verb or an adjective.

According to English grammar, if you want to have the adverb at the beginning rather the end of a sentence, it must be placed before the main verb but after auxiliary verbs.

So here, the second sentence is the correct one:

> ✔ So you’ll immediately see the notification when information crucial for you changes.

Comment: No, _crucial_ is an adjective, but can take a complement. _Information crucial for you_ = _information which is crucial for you_. While I agree with Neeku's main point, I observe that they cannot be a native English speaker, as _the English grammar_ is not colloquial in any English I am familiar with, and _at_ is the preposition used for the beginning or end of something.

Comment: Thanks for clarification @ColinFine. I edited my post. (: However I couldn't manage to make the heads or tails of that sentence without your comment, even after reading it several times. Would a comma before "*changes*" improve the readability?

Comment: It might make it clearer, though the pedants will complain that you're not allowed to separate the subject and the verb with a comma.